# DSC Node stuck in Pending status

Tags: azure-automation

When I want to renew the DSC related certificate on a node in Azure Automation DSC (for example a Windows AD Domain Controller, which is on-boarded to Azure Automation DSC as a Node). the only way I am aware of to renew the certificate (according to the MS documentation) is to un-register then re-register the node with Azure Automation DSC. This works and renews the certificate.

However, the node loses its associated to its DSC configuration document, therefore I then need to assign the configuration to the Node. When I do this is goes into 'pending' status as one would expect. However, it never comes out of pending status (in the Node overview pane or the portal), but when double-clicking the node (to see the properties of a particular node), under reports it shows the node is compliant or not compliant (depending if the node's configuration matches the DSC configuration document or not). So DSC appears to be working and reporting on the nodes compliance OK (under reports). Therefore why does the Node overview pane always show the node in 'pending' status after doing the above?

it is driving me nuts, is it a bug?

Thanks

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue, even after unregistering the node and re-registering it. Changing node configurations hasn't helped, either. Going to open a support ticket with Microsoft and hopefully post a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3917c1f1-8a4b-4224-a19b-3bf3946000ea/azure-automation-dsc-node-says-it-is-in-the-pending-state-but-is-it?forum=azureautomation) MSDN thread looks similar to issue faced by you. A copy of the answer from the thread is pasted below. Hope this helps!!

*Interesting! Perhaps I am missing something but with the given information, in general 'Pending' state show up when we assign a complied configuration to a node and in next periodic check it does change as ideally node retrieves the configuration, applies it and reports the new status. And in general 'Not Compliant' status come up when the node is in ApplyandMonitor mode and the machine is not in the desired state.
When server is registered, if the configuration mode is not set to AutoCorrect mode and if server that drift from a compliant state for any reason will remain non-compliant until they are manually corrected. To see instructions to correct it, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-remediate) document and see if it helps to resolve your issue.
If the above mentioned step(s) doesn't resolve your issue, we recommend engaging our technical support team to investigate further. So [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) are the steps to raise a support ticket with Azure technical support if you already have a support plan. But if you don't, then please send mail to AzCommunity@microsoft.com with your subscription ID and a link of this MSDN thread (for context) and we will assist you with engaging Azure technical support.*